# SVN tagging outside tags folder

Tags: svn

I'm trying to expand use of SVN outside the software group at my company.  While this may seem trivial, they would prefer to have the repo arranged like this:

- repo ->

  - project (effectively trunk)
  - project-1 (effectively first tag)
  - project-2 (effectively second tag)
  - project-3 (effectively third tag)

Basically all this does is eliminate the /tags subdirectory, and they never expect to have branches.  Is there any way to do this in SVN, but still get the warnings when someone is about to check in over a tag?

I realize this is a trivial change to how SVN is typically used, but I figured it's worth looking into if it is possible.

Comment: I read a bit more of the SVN book, and it seems that it's not going to give the warning unless the path actually includes the subdir name "tags."  It seems that I can run a script upon commit, however?  Maybe I can use that to show a warning if someone if committing outside the "project" directory?

Comment: @radarbob: "SVN does not allow commits to a tag" - RLLY?!

Comment: my bad. This is just the way we use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write pre-commit hook, in which with `svnlook dirs-changed` you can test all targets of commit (and block commit if it's in "protected" trees).

If you'll enumerate all "tags" in destination-checks (instead of blocking all commits outside `/project`), it will effectively block all commits to existing tags, but allow to create new with server-side `svn copy`. And you'll have only one small drawback of such solution - after creating new node of "tags"-family you have to fix your hook and expand taglist in it

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out this solution today.  I'm curious...there are a bunch of files that need to get updated in "project" each time that a tag is done...are pre-commit hooks powerful enough to do that?  Just renaming the files so that the last number in the filename increases by 1 would be a start, but if it could actually modify the documents too it'd be awesome.

Comment: @BigBobby - modify content of transaction in pre-commit hook is possible (theoretically), but **strictly not recommended** - you may get unpredictable results and broken data in repo

Comment: Thanks for the info.  These hooks are opening up a whole new SVN world to me that I didn't know existed!